# Use mono.cecil in a Godot build, to weave C# scripts

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I have split up my Godot project in multiple packages:

- game (Godot project)
- core (C# scripts and additional code)
- core-test

The build core code needs to be weaved with Mono.Cecil when building the game.

In Unity I did so by registering a callback to `CompilationPipeline.assemblyCompilationFinished`.

**How do I do this in Godot?**

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I have not tested any of this.*

---

**New Answer**

As far as I can tell Godot does not have this feature. Which suggest you will have to do this on .NET side (Godot 4 is using .NET (it is not mono despite the name of the download, nor something else), and MSBuild). Thus:

Add the MSBuild "AfterBuild" target, see [How to: Extend the Visual Studio Build Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms366724(v=vs.100)).

There you could use any [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task-reference?view=vs-2022), for example the [Exec task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2022), or the [CSC task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/csc-task?view=vs-2022), or a custom task with [Using task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022).

I found a couple articles that suggest this is (or was) viable:

- [Integrating DependencyPropertyWeaver Into Your Build](http://bling.github.io/blog/2011/04/17/integrating-dependencypropertyweaver/)
- [Introducing DependencyPropertyWeaver](http://bling.github.io/blog/2011/04/15/introducing-dependencypropertyweaver/)

I also found an issue about "AfterBuild" which would affect this approach: [AfterTarget in csproj gets overridden by SDKs target file.](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/841)

---

**Old Answer**

*Errata: Apparently when Godot calls `_build` the .NET has not executed yet.*

The [`EditorPlugin`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorplugin.html#editorplugin) class has a virtual method [`_build`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_editorplugin.html#class-editorplugin-method-build) that will be called before running. <strike>Thus, I believe you could hook the code you need there.</strike>

See also [Making plugins](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/plugins/editor/making_plugins.html).

Comment: _build is called before the build, not after. My c# scripts aren't build yet, then.

Comment: @SebastianBarth see updated answer. Notes: As far as I know there isn't a direct equivalent of what you want in Godot, and also I'm not aware of a way to have custom build targets for .NET in Godot. Please consider writing a feature proposal: https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues